# How to change the name of a user in kube config file with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

How do you change the `name` of a user in a kube config file with kubectl (no text editor)?

Example kube config file `stage_config.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:6443
  name: cluster.local
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster.local
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@cluster.local
current-context: kubernetes-admin@cluster.local
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

I want to do something like `kubectl config rename-user --kubeconfig ~/.kube/stage_config.yaml kubernetes-admin kubernetes-admin-1`

With the output like:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:6443
  name: cluster.local
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster.local
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@cluster.local
current-context: kubernetes-admin@cluster.local
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin-1
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

I've tried `kubectl config set` but receive the following error:

```
kubectl config set --kubeconfig ~/.kube/stage_config.yaml users.name.kubernetes-admin kubernetes-admin-1
error: can't set a map to a value: map[kubernetes-admin:0xc000c53100]
```

`kubectl config --help` shows that the `rename-context` command exists, but nothing like `rename-user` nor `rename-cluster` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQ to do the magic (just make sure your KubeConfig is in JSON).
I'm sure is possible to do it with YQ for YAML but I let someone else fill that one in. Set `CLUSTER_NAME` to your desired value.

```bash
jq '.clusters[0].name="'$CLUSTER_NAME'" | .contexts[0].context.cluster="'$CLUSTER_NAME'"' source/kubeconfig > target/kubeconfig
```